# Browser tabs timer rotates in case of asynchronous cross domain ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, webserver, cross-domain

I have jsp page1 which is proceesed from application1 hosted on tomcat1.i am making the async cross site ajax request from my browser (thru page)
to different application(cross domain request) on different webserver(node.js).what is happening is till i do not get the response(which i get after 3-4 minutes), my firefox/chrome client
tab keeps on showing processing(like timer keeps on rotating on tab and left bottom corner they show waiting for servername) which does not happen on IE. As this is the asynchronous call,
i do not want the user to feel some thing is processing on server.

**Is there a way to stop the behaviour where timer keeps on rotating
on browser tab in firefox/chrome?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may any of these things to hide the "loading" bar of chrome/firefox (hope it'll work):

1. Do your Ajax calls inside different thread (read about [Web_worker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_worker)). (This is HTML5 standard and won't work in old browsers)
2. If you're initiating the ajax call as part of page onload(), try to put it inside setTimeout() or setInterval().
3. Try to submit your request to an hidden iframe (Embed a hidden form & an iframe into your page, add your request parameters as hidden variables, set the target of the form to the name of that iframe, set the action of the form to the url of your ajax request, submit the form). This may not work since it make a hidden page load (but worth trying).